# If 2 cells are populated in Excel, subtract the third cell, otherwise return the value in one of the two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a spreadsheet for a points system. If the person competed in both divisions, I need the third cell subtracted from that sum. If they only competed in one division, I need that number returned.

For example

```
Name        A       B       C     Total (D) 
John        1       5       2        4
Sally       3       0       1        3
Peter       0       7       4        7
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula would probably work for your need:

```
=IF(AND(B2<>0,C2<>0),B2+C2-D2,B2+C2)
```

Put this is cell `E2` (given your example that John is in row 2.)

This will calculate, `IF` cell `B2` and also cell `C2` have a value of more than `0` then it will calculate `B2+C2` and subtract `D2` from it. And if  `B2` or `C2` do equal `0` then it will just sum `B2+C2`